# ASCII string to HEX value conversion over UART embedded Application

Tags: c, pic, uart, led, mplab

I am working on Some embedded project[PIC MCU] where I will receive the data over  UART..The data will contain some ascii values which I have to convert into HEX and those converted HEX value will be used further for some operation.I needed help 
So my question is anyone has the logical part how it can be done? I have done some work though..any stackoverflow thread , hint , or CODE will be highly appreaciated
Here is my code till now

```
#include "mcc_generated_files/mcc.h"
#define _XTAL_FREQ 16000000
#define FRAMESIZE 18

void main(void)
{
   uint8_t data ,i,j;
   uint8_t value;
   uint8_t RX_Buffer [] ,RGB_data[] ,HEX_data[]   ;

    // initialize the device
    SYSTEM_Initialize();
    INTERRUPT_GlobalInterruptEnable();          // Enable the Global Interrupts
    INTERRUPT_PeripheralInterruptEnable();      // Enable the Peripheral Interrupts


    do
    {
        data = EUSART_Read();             // Read received character
        for (i = 0; i<FRAMESIZE ; i++)
        {
          RX_Buffer[i] = data;
        }

        EUSART_Write(data);               // Echo back the data received
        }while(!RCIF);        //check if any data is received

        // my UART data command starts with R and ends with '\n'
        if(RX_Buffer[0]=='R' && RX_Buffer[FRAMESIZE-1] == '\n')
        {
             LATAbits.LATA2   = 1;          //check flag
            __delay_ms(2000);
             LATAbits.LATA2   = 0;

            for (j = 0 ; j = 5; j++ )               // get the RGB value in separate array
            {
                RGB_data[j] = RX_Buffer[j+3];
                HEX_data[value] = RGB_data[j]/16 ;
              // so I am somewhat stuck how can I collect the UART data {for eg "RGBFF00A0AA" is my command which will be in ascii
               if (HEX_data[value] <=9)
                {
                   HEX_data[value] += '0';                    
                }
                else 
                {
                    HEX_data[value]=HEX_data[value]-10+'A';
                }

            }

        }
```

}

Comment: First of all you should delegate conversion to a function, you need to write, and not do it in the `main` function.

Comment: Second, you should format your source code properly. Right now, it looks like a mess.

Comment: Your title says *"ASCII to hex"*, but your code converts a binary value to ASCII.  Do you guys understand the difference?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have stdio, converting an ASCII input to HEX is trivial.

```
void AsciiToHex(char * src, char * dest)
{
  while(*src)
  {
    sprintf(dest + strlen(dest), " %02X", *src);
    src++;
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

In small microcontrollers (attiny, PIC 16F, 8051 and others) you will not have stdio available... In that case, you will need a more hands on approach, something like the following code:

```
void AsciiToHex(char * src, char * dest)
{
  char hex[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
  while(*src)
    {
      char low, high;
      high = *src >> 4; // high nibble
      low = *src & 0x0f; // low nibble
      *dest = hex[high];
      dest++;
      *dest = hex[low];
      dest++;
      *dest = ' ';
      dest++;
      src++;
    }
  *dest = 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess Using Micrchip ,MPLAB stdio lib is not working as it is purely compile for embedded project...I tried to find this but I don't think It will work..If it's , I Post it here as answer for those who will find for it

Comment: Microchip does use stdio, but only for high end microcontrollers... 18F or better as far as I know. You will need a more hands on approach then... I will shortly post on this answer...

Comment: Your **AsciiToHex()** routine does not live up to its name.  Nor does it convert properly even it it was correctly named (i.e. binary "strings" are not NULL terminated).  Also binary values require type unsigned.

Comment: that is easy to fix... just add a parameter to specify the size of the binary string and decrement it each iteration of the loop and test it instead of src... Besides, unsigned does nothing in this case. i used no calculation that make use of signal...

Comment: @LuizMenezes Okay I wait for your reply on this...The more specifically my question is more related to this question..The thread is from microchip forum -> http://www.microchip.com/forums/m552563.aspx

Comment: @Garryp  I tried to convert the string to hex directly, but you can use itoa instead... My code would probably run faster.

Comment: @Garryp And on another note, you are not buffering the uart input... it seems that you want to convert to hex in real time, and unlike sawdust ranting, your string does have a terminator, it just is not 0... it is /n. Do you have an output buffer for the HEX string?

Comment: Hello Guys, Thanks for replying ..I tried string functions like strcpy and strtol to extract and convert values in HEX...Thanks everyone..I will make it post –

Comment: @garryp then mark thw question as answered, please.